# Columns hidden/missing inside phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I click on the "explore" tab it would normally show me the data inside my table, but for some reason it wont show me all the columns. It only shows me 5 columns and the rest are hidden. The exact same thing happens when I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabs`
```

However, I do find the column and the data inside it when I specifically search for it:

```
SELECT `prevpage` FROM `tabs`
```

When I click on the dropdown arrow on the < T > column above the edit options I can choose which columns I want to show. There are two empty column names inside the list (exactly like two columns are missing), and when I choose to view them all the content inside them says `NULL` while its not.

Any idea's on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you running the "SELECT * FROM `tabs`" from phpmyadmin or from the terminal?

Comment: phpmyadmin, when I click on "SQL" I can insert my own SQL and run it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar issue. However, the resolution was **a lot different** and **EASIER to apply**.

The issue was actually caused by 'Storage Engine'. All you need to do to clear this error is to:

```
     - Go to the table that is having the trouble of hidden column-> 
     - Got to 'Operation' Tab->
     - Under 'Table Options' ->
     - For 'Storage Engine' Option, select the one that is consistent with
       the one that you are   using throughout the table. 
     - Refresh the table-> Wala! The missing column reappear in browse tab!
```

***In the case for myself, I am using 'MyISAM' as default but was using 'InnoDB' for that specific troubled table.***

It has took my an hour to figure out what happened and NOTHING was available online for this situation. Hope it helps one who has the same problem.

Comment: this solution works. go home phpmyadmin your drunk !

Answer (score 2):

if u still interested in how to solve this..
just recently i got the same problem..
first of all, you must exporting your troublesome table..
and then, drop the table..
finally, importing the file to your database..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never solved this problem, I just quited with whatever I was doing (I forgot what it was), but I'm sure it might be useful to others.

Comment: I just encountered this problem, I can easily drop the table and rebuild it which will hopefully solve the issue but it's not knowing what is happening that is most troublesome..

Answer (score 1):

My issue was with an indexed foreign key.  I reset my indexes and that resolved my issue, since the previous answers didn't work for me.

I've been leaching here for years...nice to HOPEFULLY give back for once!

Answer (score 0):

Clear browser cache. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. Logging out and in again solved it for me. Might help someone ending up here.